# HTML CSS FLEX issue, divs aren't centering correctly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Basically, the apprentice container needs to be on left, and then the div that opens after the onClick needs to be centered (the yellow dotted in image 1)  I've noticed it looks different on different monitor sizes.

Here two pictures of my progress thus far, i've dotted some of the containers to hopefully help you guys.

I hope everything makes sense.

[image: Image 1 with buttons not clicked]

[image: Image 2 with buttons clicked]

Here's the HTML:

```css
.body2 {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

.body3 {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction: row; */
  /* align-items: center; */
  border: 2px dotted orange;
}

.body-flexstart {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-self: flex-start;
  width: 400px;
  /* flex-direction: row; */
  /* flex-flow: row wrap; */
  /* justify-content: space-around; */
  /* align-items: flex-start; */
  /* border: 1px dotted green; */
}

.column1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px dotted yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="body2">
  <div class="body-flexstart">
    <div class="column1">
      <div onclick="console.log('clicked')" id="button" class="test1">
        <h1 class="itemcomponenttextheader">Apprentice</h1>
        <h1 class="itemcomponenttextheader">1 - 75</h1>
      </div>
      <table id="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="tableheader">Mats</th>
            <th class="tableheader">Amount</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="professionheader3">
              <div class="matslist">
                <div class="matsicon2">
                  <img class="matsiconlist" src="./enchantingimages/inv_enchant_duststrange.jpg"> Strange Dust</div>
            </td>
            <td class="professionheader3">150x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="professionheader3">
              <div class="matslist">
                <div class="matsicon2">
                  <img class="matsiconlist" src="./enchantingimages/soul-dust.png"> Soul Dust</div>
            </td>
            <td class="professionheader3">90x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="professionheader3">
              <div class="matslist">
                <div class="matsicon2">
                  <img class="matsiconlist" src="./enchantingimages/vision-dust.gif"> Vision Dust</div>
            </td>
            <td class="professionheader3">170x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="professionheader3">
              <div class="matslist">
                <div class="matsicon2">
                  <img class="matsiconlist" src="./enchantingimages/dream-dust.gif"> Dream Dust</div>
            </td>
            <td class="professionheader3">300x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>
      <div onclick="console.log('clicked')" id="button1" class="test1">
        <h1 class="itemcomponenttextheader">Apprentice</h1>
        <h1 class="itemcomponenttextheader">1 - 75</h1>
      </div>
      <table id="table1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="tableheader">Mats</th>
            <th class="tableheader">Amount</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="professionheader3">
              <div class="matslist">
                <div class="matsicon2">
                  <img class="matsiconlist" src="./enchantingimages/inv_enchant_duststrange.jpg"> Strange Dust</div>
            </td>
            <td class="professionheader3">150x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="professionheader3">
              <div class="matslist">
                <div class="matsicon2">
                  <img class="matsiconlist" src="./enchantingimages/soul-dust.png"> Soul Dust</div>
            </td>
            <td class="professionheader3">90x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="professionheader3">
              <div class="matslist">
                <div class="matsicon2">
                  <img class="matsiconlist" src="./enchantingimages/vision-dust.gif"> Vision Dust</div>
            </td>
            <td class="professionheader3">170x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="body3">
        <div class="box2" id="box">
          <p class="professionheader3">A</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box2" id="box1">
          <p class="professionheader3">B</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I think this will be easier if you used some dummy content(simplifying the example). It would be much easier to read. Also, you should check support for `justify-self`

Comment: @Huangism hey thanks for the response, would you suggest taking out a lot of the info and just try making boxes to visually see?

Comment: You want the `AB` container to be centered in the middle of the page all the time? @krondog

Comment: @krondog yes, the info isn't the issue and it just adds to the clutter. You just need to post the actual issue, the whole button pressing doesn't even come into play because we are just concerned with the layout of the entire thing when all the container is showing up. You could just have a couple of boxes with colours and describe what you tried and what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nest the `div class="body3">` inside new `div` and add this:

`{ display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;}`

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cdgzjf7L/)

```css
.body2 {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

.body3 {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction: row; */
  /* align-items: center; */
  border: 2px dotted orange;
}

.new--div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.body-flexstart {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-self: flex-start;
  width: 400px;
  /* flex-direction: row; */
  /* flex-flow: row wrap; */
  /* justify-content: space-around; */
  /* align-items: flex-start; */
  /* border: 1px dotted green; */
}

.column1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px dotted yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="body2">
  <div class="body-flexstart">
    <div class="column1">
      <div onclick="console.log('clicked')" id="button" class="test1">
        <h1 class="itemcomponenttextheader">Apprentice</h1>
        <h1 class="itemcomponenttextheader">1 - 75</h1>
      </div>
      <table id="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="tableheader">Mats</th>
            <th class="tableheader">Amount</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="professionheader3">
              <div class="matslist">
                <div class="matsicon2">
                  <img class="matsiconlist" src="./enchantingimages/inv_enchant_duststrange.jpg"> Strange Dust</div>
            </td>
            <td class="professionheader3">150x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="professionheader3">
              <div class="matslist">
                <div class="matsicon2">
                  <img class="matsiconlist" src="./enchantingimages/soul-dust.png"> Soul Dust</div>
            </td>
            <td class="professionheader3">90x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="professionheader3">
              <div class="matslist">
                <div class="matsicon2">
                  <img class="matsiconlist" src="./enchantingimages/vision-dust.gif"> Vision Dust</div>
            </td>
            <td class="professionheader3">170x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="professionheader3">
              <div class="matslist">
                <div class="matsicon2">
                  <img class="matsiconlist" src="./enchantingimages/dream-dust.gif"> Dream Dust</div>
            </td>
            <td class="professionheader3">300x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>
      <div onclick="console.log('clicked')" id="button1" class="test1">
        <h1 class="itemcomponenttextheader">Apprentice</h1>
        <h1 class="itemcomponenttextheader">1 - 75</h1>
      </div>
      <table id="table1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="tableheader">Mats</th>
            <th class="tableheader">Amount</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="professionheader3">
              <div class="matslist">
                <div class="matsicon2">
                  <img class="matsiconlist" src="./enchantingimages/inv_enchant_duststrange.jpg"> Strange Dust</div>
            </td>
            <td class="professionheader3">150x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="professionheader3">
              <div class="matslist">
                <div class="matsicon2">
                  <img class="matsiconlist" src="./enchantingimages/soul-dust.png"> Soul Dust</div>
            </td>
            <td class="professionheader3">90x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="professionheader3">
              <div class="matslist">
                <div class="matsicon2">
                  <img class="matsiconlist" src="./enchantingimages/vision-dust.gif"> Vision Dust</div>
            </td>
            <td class="professionheader3">170x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="new--div">
        <div class="body3">
          <div class="box2" id="box">
            <p class="professionheader3">A</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box2" id="box1">
            <p class="professionheader3">B</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```